# Is anyone who tries to deny the holy Qur'an is perfect blasphemous?

Tags: quran, blasphemy

Given that the Holy qur'an is the indisputable word of Allah (swt), is anyone who tries to claim that it's not perfection directly attacking Allah and insulting 2bn Muslims?

And so, what is the appropriate punishment for their Blasphemy?

Comment: If it was "indisputable", then they wouldn't be claiming otherwise. If they **are** claiming otherwise (which many clearly are), then it is not "indisputable". I acknowledge that *you* do not dispute it, and nor do many Muslims. But that does not make it "indisputable". But all that aside, wouldn't it be better to just respond by showing clearly and logically how the person's criticism is misplaced?

Comment: Please be specific. What do you mean by deny its perfection? Do you mean deny that it's from Allah, or deny that it has any mistakes in it, or something else? Ditto for what you mean by "blasphemous."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually the Quran does not contain any sort of "blasphemy" law. These are derivations drawn by early Muslim scholars from the Torah.

> "**And he that blasphemeth the name of the LORD, he shall surely be put to death;** all the congregation shall certainly stone him; as well the stranger, as the home-born, when he blasphemeth the Name, shall be put to death. (Leviticus 24:16)

The Quran requires us to be patient when we hear things we dont like.

> You will surely be tested in your possessions and in yourselves. **And you will surely hear from those who were given the Scripture before you and from those who associate others with Allah much abuse. But if you are patient and fear Allah - indeed, that is of the matters [worthy] of determination.** (Quran 3:186)

Insulting Muslims or Islam is a favorite pass time in todays time and the reactions is actually the result of years of unresolved local conflicts.

Also, please see how a muslim is expected to handle blasphemy [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/2633/342)

Comment: I don't think that denial of the Quran by a non-Muslim would be considered blasphemy, but the statement that blasphemy law has no basis in the Quran and Sunnah and is derived from the Torah is wrong. Scholars claim to derive it from e.g [[9:12](https://quran.com/9/12)] as well as events from the life of the Prophet.

Answer (score 7):

> is anyone who tries to claim that it's not perfection directly attacking Allah and insulting 2bn Muslims?

There are roughly 7 billion people on this planet. I could re-phrase that statement as:

> is anyone who tries to claim that it **is** perfection directly insulting 5bn non-Muslims?

The answer to both is simply: "no". We just disagree on a point of philosophy. There is no more "insult" when I say "I do not believe the teachings of Islam" than there is when you say "I do believe the teachings of Islam" (where we may incidentally substitute the word "Islam" for any other point of debate, religious or otherwise). So it would *absolutely* be a good thing if everyone stopped talking in terms of "appropriate punishment", and instead focused on:

> {Here's} what I believe, {here's} what you believe; that's cool. Now that we understand each-other's views, and since it is particularly unlikely that either of us is going to change views suddenly: how can we best get along without antagonizing each-other? What middle ground can we build upon to just *get along*?

Perhaps the only "insult" here is expecting those who disagree with your view to remain silent, under fear of "appropriate punishment", instead of being offered the same right to speak their views, on equal footing:

> {That's} your view? Thanks for taking the time to tell me that - that's interesting. {Here's} what I happen to believe. Thanks for taking the time to listen to my views.

Comment: I am summarizing some over-long comments; the originals are [here](http://pastie.org/4904566), and I can reinstate them here if desired. "owari" notes that there is a difference (akin to the difference between light and dark), which I interpret as (paraphrasing) "because Islam is right, and the others aren't" - I responded that this is subjective. "Hanif" objects that my post is disrespectful; I do not agree, but without more explanation as to what is offensive I cannot comment further. "Aamir" reported finding no offence. I think that brings us up to date fairly concisely...

Answer (score 1):

> is anyone who tries to claim that it's not perfection directly
>   attacking Allah and insulting 2bn Muslims?

**No it is not.** There is very clear difference between insult and difference of opinion. Not only the non Muslims but we Muslims should also have to understand this difference. For example the movie clip "Innocence of Muslims" is clearly insult and provocation attempt but if someone deny that Quran is word of God and s/he does not believe in Islam or Prophet Muhammad then it is not insult, it is just an opinion.

> And so, what is the appropriate punishment for their Blasphemy?

**Nothing.** When Prophet Muhammad(PBUH) moved to Madina (in Saudia Arabia now a days) from Mecca there were so many Jews living there. He had agreements with them. One example:

> Historians (see Sahih Bukhari, Tradition Number 1311) report that as a
>   funeral of a Jew passed before Prophet Muhammad [peace and blessings
>   be upon him], as a sign of respect he stood up. In doing this, he
>   showed respect and shared in the feeling of sorrow with Jewish family
>   and community. "Why did you stand up for a Jewish funeral?" he was
>   asked. The Prophet replied: "Is it not a human soul?"

As a Muslim my question to you as another Muslim:

Non Muslims don't belive in Quran because they don't believe that it is word of God BUT we Muslims believe that Quran is word of God so doing anything opposite to Quran is denying that it is word of God. You and I both know that more than 90% Muslims, now a days, don't act according to Quran. We `lie`, `don't keep promises`, `bear false witness`, `don't treat our wives and sub ordinates respectfully`, `don't pray`, `don't do our work sincerely` etc. etc. So what should be the punishment for us (Muslims) for denying Quran by our actions?

Comment: Thank you for the answer - I've already awarded the answer (and it would be wrong to unaward it)... but +1

Comment: @Hanif It's what you accept as an answer. So there is nothing wrong in accepting another answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Qur'an is ordinarily considered perfect.  After all, it's a miracle from Allah.  Allah states *We have not neglected in the Register a thing* ([Qur'an 6:38](https://quran.com/6/38)) and *We will be its guardian* ([Qur'an 15:9](https://quran.com/15/9)).

Depending on the nature of the claim, denying the Qur'an's perfect nature in a tangible way (such as asserting that it contains errors) could be considered to be contradicting such ayat.  This may in turn amount to *Kufr ul-Juhud* (disbelief out of rejection); see [SunnahOnline.com](http://sunnahonline.com/library/beliefs-and-methodology/87-types-of-kufr-disbelief) (Adapted from Tafsir Ibn Kathir).

Regarding:

> Given that the Holy qur'an is the indisputable word of Allah (swt), is anyone who tries to claim that it's not perfection directly attacking Allah and insulting 2bn Muslims?

Muslims will likely think that person is mistaken, and should research the topic more.  They may consider it offensive, depending on the strength of the claim.

Regarding:

> And so, what is the appropriate punishment for their Blasphemy?

Blasphemy in fiqh is both interpreted and implemented in various ways.  As Wikipedia summarizes it:

> Different traditional schools of jurisprudence prescribe different punishment for blasphemy, depending on whether the blasphemer is Muslim or non-Muslim, a man or a woman. In the modern Muslim world, the laws pertaining to blasphemy vary by county, and some countries prescribe punishments consisting of fines, imprisonment, flogging, hanging, or beheading.
>   <sub>[Islam and Blasphemy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islam_and_blasphemy), Wikipedia</sub>

Here's one example implementation from Selangor, Malaysia (sourced via [esyariah.gov.my](http://www.esyariah.gov.my/)) that's relevant to the Qur'an in particular:

> Section 9. Deriding etc., verses of Al-Quran or Hadith.  Any person who derides, insults, ridicules or brings into contempt by his words or acts the verses of Al-Quran or Hadith shall be guilty of an offence and shall be liable on conviction to a fine not exceeding five thousand ringgit or to imprisonment for a term not exceeding three years or to both.