# What is ruling for Blasphemy in Islam?

Tags: sharia, blasphemy

I have heard from sources that its death penalty. What is the actual ruling according to Sharia?

Edit:

A related [answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/2950/46) on a question suggests that there is no blasphemy law scholars have derived it from torah. Is it true?

Comment: AFAIK the rulings came later and have no evidence from Quran and Sunnah to support them. But I might be wrong. The Quran says one should leave a majlis poeple are mocking of Allah etc.

Comment: This is well answered at Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islam_and_blasphemy#Punishment