# People insulting the noble Prophet online

Tags: quran, prophet-muhammad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How should insults to the Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) be handled?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2625/how-should-insults-to-the-prophet-muhammad-pbuh-be-handled)

What should we do when we discover people (deliberately or otherwise) insulting the noble prophet? Even on this board we've seen (non Muslim) members essentially call him a fake and a liar while on other sites they are even more vicious with the insults.

As Muslims, should we yet again ignore the provocations? and how far should we let them go? Is there any guidance in the holy Quran against those who attack us and our beliefs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Insulting back is the worst decision, I think. Holy Quran has prohibited us from insulting even idols:

> وَلاَ تَسُبُّواْ الَّذِينَ يَدْعُونَ مِن دُونِ اللّهِ فَيَسُبُّواْ
> اللّهَ عَدْوًا بِغَيْرِ عِلْمٍ - الانعام 17
>
> And do not insult those they invoke other than Allah , lest they insult Allah in enmity without knowledge.

What should we do? It depends on the person who is doing so. There are some cases that the people doing so aim to attract the traffic and raises the arguments, or our reply has no effect to what is he doing. In this condition I think just a reminder that proves to every other visitor the insulter is far from the basics of a constructive dialog and forgetting that website could be enough.

But if you believe your behavior can change the behavior of the insulter, you may provide some nice stories of how Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) treated the people who insulted him - like his visit from the Jewish neighborhood who was sick - can be constructive.