# Basic replies to anti Islamic bigotry

Tags: islamic-philosophy, dawah

I think is a question i can ask on Islam, and correct me if I'm wrong (first time here) but last night i had a room-mate who was spouting off a lot of anti Islamic hate speech, things along the lines of

- 'Islam is an evil and hateful religion'
- 'Muslims will lie to non Muslims to further their cause'

to outright wrong things like

- 'all Muslims must die'

and other things which have no point being listed here due to their outright hatred. and being in favor of tolerance i tried to correct him, but i know next to nothing about Islamic doctrine. so my question is, what are some good responses to your standard anti Islamic rant?

Is there a good English source to learn basic Islamic doctrinal belief so i can educate myself enough to combat future attacks on it? I would be willing to read anything up to twenty pages (that's all that i have time for). when faced with a situation like this should one just conclude that their is no changing his mind and remain silent?

Comment: http://www.islamhouse.com/d/files/en/ih_books/single/en_Common_Questions.pdf

Comment: http://www.whyislam.org/

Comment: I would also recommend that you visit Dr Zakir Naik's site (irf.net). http://www.irf.net/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=255&Itemid=199

Comment: possible duplicate of [How should insults to the Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) be handled?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2625/how-should-insults-to-the-prophet-muhammad-pbuh-be-handled)

Comment: "All Muslims must die" is not an *argument* (i.e., a debating point). It's a simple expression of bigotry. No response required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Don't argue with a fool, he will drag you down to his level and beat you with experience.

But if someone is reasonable enough for you to argue with, then learn your knowledge about Islam and show him reference to convince him. As you are about to.

But if he is like how you describe, then there is no need to get upset, for Allah will judge his ignorance and arrogance. Behave the way a Muslim is supposed to behave, remain peaceful and refrain from anger and hatred. **Actions speak louder than words**. **The best "combat" is through your tolerance and well-behaving**. Of course, even after that, there are still people who have their minds set in stone with bias, then let hem be.

I really doubt that by just getting into discussion with him you will be able to have him completely realize his mistakes and say "O, I have wronged". And there are more people like that in the world than you know. So either get into a healthy respectful discussion, or don't let him be on your mind at all. If you are kind enough, pray to Allah for his guidance.

This is just my personal point of view and Allah knows the best.

Comment: Also, question his reference. Why do you draw this conclusion, who did you talk to, how many people did you talk to, what's your main source of information, how many people are like that and how many Muslims are there in total? Did you read the Quran? and along such lines. Ignorance breaks itself when you keep questioning it.