# Is it justified to kill someone for disrespecting our Prophet Muhammad SAWS

Tags: hadith, prophet-muhammad, justice

Recently in France, a teacher was beheaded by someone because of his act of showing some drawings in his class. I just want to know is it really justified to kill someone who disrespects our Prophet Muhammad(SAWS)? From what I have learned so far that our prophet was extremely kind to those who tortured him verbally or physically(by throwing trash). So is it really justifiable to kill someone for disrespecting our prophet?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should insults to the Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) be handled?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2625/how-should-insults-to-the-prophet-muhammad-pbuh-be-handled) also see [What formal, doctrinal guidance is there for how a Muslim should personally respond to deliberate, gratuitous abuse of Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/48735/20218)

Comment: @UmH it partially does. I still have some doubts about the verbal abuse/mockery part.