# According to sharia law, if a kafir critizes islam will he be Punished?

Tags: sharia

Is a disbeliever critizes islam, quran, Prophet Muhammad will he/she be Punished under sharia law?

For example if he asks why idol worship is prohibited in islam. Idol worship do not harm anyone so why is is prohibited.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should insults to the Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) be handled?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2625/how-should-insults-to-the-prophet-muhammad-pbuh-be-handled). Also see [What formal, doctrinal guidance is there for how a Muslim should personally respond to deliberate, gratuitous abuse of Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/48699/)

Comment: @UmH there is a difference between criticism and abuse( blasphemy). When you criticize someone you use logic. Criticism is not an insult but disagreement

Comment: You should edit your post and consider giving examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between criticism and blasphemy (insults). Mufti Muhammad Shafi wrote in his tafsir:

> **Honest critical study of Islam by Protected Non-Muslim Citizens of Dar**
> **al-Islam is possible - vilification is not**
>
> Some commentators have interpreted the words: طَعَنوا في دينِكُم
> (speak evil of your faith) to mean that speaking evil of the Faith of
> Muslims is included under contravention of pledge. A person who speaks
> evil of Islam and the Shari’ah of Islam cannot continue to be a party
> to the treaty with Muslims. **But, according to a consensus of Muslim**
> **jurists, it means vilification that is done to insult and belittle**
> **Islam and Muslims, openly and publicly.** **Honest intellectual criticism**
> **while conducting research into problems and rulings remains exempt**
> **from its purview - then, it is not supposed to be vilification in its**
> **lexical sense.**  **Therefore, for non-Muslim citizens of Dar al-Islam,**
> **any honest intellectual criticism can be allowed**, but what cannot be
> allowed is vilification, contempt, insult or outrage against Islam.
>
> [Ma'ariful Qur'an 19:12](https://islamicstudies.info/quran/maarif/maarif.php?sura=9&verse=12&fbclid=IwAR3CwPXIzMQ6Fw31iw_rTfqQ4Iu528APNqKMH6LBz9P7uw0dbeVf894DtmY)

So according to most fuqaha, honest intellectual criticism is allowed but not blasphemy (i.e insults/vilification) which according to most fuqaha is a hadd offense, punishable by death.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: Can you cite some older sources for this.