# What should be the Muslims attitude towards ex muslims

Tags: sharia

In an Islamic country, if a muslim changes his/her religion, what should be the muslims attitude towards the person?

Actually I am told by someone(who quoted a Hadith) that such persons should be killed by the goveronment (which is clearly injustice)

Comment: also, http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1739/how-do-we-reconcile-the-apostasy-ruling-with-al-baqarah-2256

Comment: I am sorry I don't feel satisfied with the answers.

Comment: You are free not to like it. But according to the policy of this site, this question has already been asked and the answers are already there. Soon your question will be closed by other members because it is a duplicate question.

Comment: @HashirOmer not commenting on whether the question is a duplicate of the aforementioned. But if the question has already been asked then there's no point in asking the same question over again. You could set a bounty on it for it to gain attention and upvote it. HTH.

Answer (score -1):

1. Knowing that guidance comes from God and God alone.
2. Making sure that as a Muslim, you do not act in a way that will LOCK the door to this person's Islam. Instead, with your actions, words, and behavior, allow the person to see the beauty of Islam on a consistent basis.
3. If the person is constantly speaking about their apostasy and making a spectacle of it, protect your children and younger family members from their discourse.

Clearly, **something** - emotional, intellectual, or spiritual has occurred that has caused this person to leave Islam. It is entirely possible, they didn't even understand Islam properly in the first place.

The job of the everyday Muslim is not to act as the Qadi, Amir-ul-Mu'mineen, or authority. The job of the every Muslim should be to exhibit Prophetic character and manners when dealing with anyone.

As long as the person is alive, they may come back to Islam. Allow that by not reacting with harshness. If you are friends with this person, see if you can answer their questions or take them to someone who can. If not, leave them be.

Allah guides whom He wills, and Allah knows best.

Comment: Actually I am told by someone(who quoted a Hadith) that such persons should be killed (which is clearly injustice)

Comment: Hashir, taking one Hadith and using it to make a legal judgement is not the way of Islamic scholarship.

There are thousands of ahadeeth, and in order to use them in Law, one must understand their chains of narration, the level of authenticity, their classification, their arabic language, the legal rulings regarding the issue from the time of the Sahabah, and reconcile them with the rest of Islamic text.

If a person is quoting one Hadith as a legal proof, unfortunately they don't understand Islamic Law and should not be relied upon.

Comment: Additionally, the responsibility of the Muslims in general, and the responsibilities of the authorities are different. Islamic Law makes a strong distinction between the everyday person and the governor of a territory.

Here is a good link with a better answer:
http://www.suhaibwebb.com/islam-studies/islam-101/misconceptions/freedom-of-religion-and-apostasy-in-islam-by-dr-ahmed-raysuni/

Here is an excellent video as well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9CdxkF3q44E

Comment: -1, I recommend reading his question again. He was asking about the penalty of those who leave Islam.