# Tabari 9:69 "Killing Unbelievers is a small matter to us" The words of Muhammad, prophet of Islam

Tags: non-muslim, hadith-interpretation, war

A Non-muslim says that Islam is barbaric, and put this before me:

Tabari 9:69 "Killing Unbelievers is a small matter to us" The words of Muhammad, prophet of Islam.

However, he is willing to engage in a healthy discussion. How do i effectively explain to him that his perception is wrong?

Comment: what is context of the said statement ? if it is in war where Muslims are attacked by Unbelievers, then there is nothing wrong in statement.

Comment: @Ziyad that's what i want to know. As i have mentioned, i am unfamiliar with this hadith. So i request background so that i could answer him

Comment: Hello and welcome to [islam.se]. We generally require questions to show some effort. And this doesn't (http://www.frontpagemag.com/2013/david-solway/re-interpreting-the-koran/). Plus how do you explain effectively is a quite opinion-based, the type of question this site is not meant for. Please go through [ask] and the [help/on-topic].

Comment: Kafir or Ahl al-Kitāb?  Just FYI, other religions have acted similarly even though they may not have explicitly said it.  For example the Crusades, Abyssinia vs Somalia, Buddhist uprising, etc.

Comment: Can you give direct link to the hadith, with Arabic.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do we reconcile the apostasy ruling with Al-Baqarah 2:256](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1739/how-do-we-reconcile-the-apostasy-ruling-with-al-baqarah-2256)

Comment: related [Is punishment for leaving Islam death?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/221/is-punishment-for-leaving-islam-death) and [Punishment for apostasy in Islam](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/23548/punishment-for-apostasy-in-islam) and there are many other related questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I have researched these are words of Thabit b. Qays b. Shammas not that of the Prophet (PBUH). The Arabic text is available [here](http://library.islamweb.net/hadith/display_hbook.php?bk_no=334&hid=812&pid=156685) and the English translation [here](https://books.google.com.pk/books?id=XxG8BsHNw-MC&lpg=PA69&ots=zpEynw1oOm&dq=Tabari%209%3A69%20small&pg=PA69#v=onepage&q=Tabari%209:69%20small&f=false):

> ومن كفر جاهدناه في الله أبدا **وكان قتله علينا يسيرا**
>
> as for the one who disbelieves, we will fight him forever in the cause of God **and killing him is a small matter to us**

The sentence was spoken when a deputation of Banu Tamim visited the Prophet after the conquest of Mecca ***to compete in oratory***. Therefore, it was just rhetoric.

Comment: I disagree with a_fan. It is understood that if the silence of the prophet signifies that an action or statement is approved by him. That is the concept of silent approval in several Ahadith. So I think that this statement by Thabit bin Qays completely represents islam

Comment: @user19635 - This is your flawed and biased approach towards Islam. You have to understand the proper context of the narration.

Comment: It would be better if you can provide the complete context of the narration.

Comment: @user19635 - There is no such thing as "silent approval" in Hadith sciences. You are acting as if you are a Hadith expert.

Comment: @user19635 - These are the words of Thabit B. Qays, not Prophet (Sallallahu'alayhiwassalam) of Islam.

Answer (score -1):

Hadith are graded in authenticity as *sahih*, *hassan*, *da'if* and *mawdu* from the most authentic to the unreliable. But the Qu'ran itself outranks the Hadith, being the uncreated words of Allah Himself.

And in Q.5:48, we have

> For each of you We have appointed a divine law and a way of life. Had Allah so willed He could have made you one people; but so that He might try you by that which he has bestowed upon you [He willed otherwise]. Therefore, compete in doing good. Unto Allah ye will all return, and He will enlighten you concerning that wherein he differ

This explains itself and needs no explanation.