# According to Quran is leaving Islam a sin?

Tags: apostasy, quran-only

If it is then is there a punishment listed? I dont want answers from Hadees, only from Quran.

Comment: There aren't any. All of the references are from hadith. Personally, I don't follow hadith that contradict the Quran as they could be mistaken, which is in this case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do we reconcile the apostasy ruling with Al-Baqarah 2:256](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1739/how-do-we-reconcile-the-apostasy-ruling-with-al-baqarah-2256)

Answer (score 1):

> According to Quran is leaving Islam a sin?  If it is then is there a punishment listed? I dont want answers from Hadees, only from Quran.

The one who intentionally and willingly rejects Allah after he/she had Iman, then Allah's wrath is upon them and they will be punished (Quran 16:106):

> **مَن كَفَرَ بِاللَّهِ مِن بَعْدِ إِيمَانِهِ إِلَّا مَنْ أُكْرِهَ وَقَلْبُهُ مُطْمَئِنٌّ بِالْإِيمَانِ وَلَٰكِن مَّن شَرَحَ بِالْكُفْرِ صَدْرًا فَعَلَيْهِمْ غَضَبٌ مِّنَ اللَّهِ وَلَهُمْ عَذَابٌ عَظِيمٌ
>   Whoso disbelieveth (kafara) in Allah after his belief (Eemaanihi) - save him who is forced thereto and whose heart is still content with the Faith (Eemaan) - but whoso findeth ease in disbelief (bil-Kofr): On them is wrath from Allah. Theirs will be an awful doom.**

Allah doesn't mention the exact punishment, but we know the person will be punished.  This is in reference to the hereafter.

However, there's no worldly capital punishment for the one who leaves Islam, unless they join the enemy and become hostile (Quran 4:89-91):

> **وَدُّوا لَوْ تَكْفُرُونَ كَمَا كَفَرُوا فَتَكُونُونَ سَوَاءً ۖ فَلَا تَتَّخِذُوا مِنْهُمْ أَوْلِيَاءَ حَتَّىٰ يُهَاجِرُوا فِي سَبِيلِ اللَّهِ ۚ فَإِن تَوَلَّوْا فَخُذُوهُمْ وَاقْتُلُوهُمْ حَيْثُ وَجَدتُّمُوهُمْ ۖ وَلَا تَتَّخِذُوا مِنْهُمْ وَلِيًّا وَلَا نَصِيرًا
>   إِلَّا الَّذِينَ يَصِلُونَ إِلَىٰ قَوْمٍ بَيْنَكُمْ وَبَيْنَهُم مِّيثَاقٌ أَوْ جَاءُوكُمْ حَصِرَتْ صُدُورُهُمْ أَن يُقَاتِلُوكُمْ أَوْ يُقَاتِلُوا قَوْمَهُمْ ۚ وَلَوْ شَاءَ اللَّهُ لَسَلَّطَهُمْ عَلَيْكُمْ فَلَقَاتَلُوكُمْ ۚ فَإِنِ اعْتَزَلُوكُمْ فَلَمْ يُقَاتِلُوكُمْ وَأَلْقَوْا إِلَيْكُمُ السَّلَمَ فَمَا جَعَلَ اللَّهُ لَكُمْ عَلَيْهِمْ سَبِيلًا
>   سَتَجِدُونَ آخَرِينَ يُرِيدُونَ أَن يَأْمَنُوكُمْ وَيَأْمَنُوا قَوْمَهُمْ كُلَّ مَا رُدُّوا إِلَى الْفِتْنَةِ أُرْكِسُوا فِيهَا ۚ فَإِن لَّمْ يَعْتَزِلُوكُمْ وَيُلْقُوا إِلَيْكُمُ السَّلَمَ وَيَكُفُّوا أَيْدِيَهُمْ فَخُذُوهُمْ وَاقْتُلُوهُمْ حَيْثُ ثَقِفْتُمُوهُمْ ۚ وَأُولَٰئِكُمْ جَعَلْنَا لَكُمْ عَلَيْهِمْ سُلْطَانًا مُّبِينًا**
>
> **They wish you would disbelieve as they disbelieved so you would be alike. So do not take from among them allies until they emigrate for the cause of Allah . But if they turn away, then seize them and kill them wherever you find them and take not from among them any ally or helper.**
>
> **Except for those who take refuge with a people between yourselves and whom is a treaty or those who come to you, their hearts strained at fighting you or fighting their own people. And if Allah had willed, He could have given them power over you, and they would have fought you. So if they remove themselves from you and do not fight you and offer you peace, then Allah has not made for you a cause against them.**
>
> **You will find others who wish to obtain security from you and obtain security from their people. Every time they are returned to disbelief, they fall back into it. So if they do not withdraw from you or offer you peace or restrain their hands, then seize them and kill them wherever you overtake them. And those - We have made for you against them a clear authorization.**