# Apostasy law and free decision on faith

Tags: apostasy

If apostasy is a crime that is to be punished, like in many Muslim countries, how can a Muslim's decision to believe in Allah considered as free if it is influenced by fear of punishment?

Comment: See also: "[How do we reconcile the apostasy ruling with Al-Baqarah 2:256](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/1739/9123)".

Comment: This is more opinionated answer however from a Quranic perspective, an apostate will be punished only if he/she becomes an enemy combatant.  Otherwise, people are free to believe whatever they like as long as they contribute positive to society and not become hostile..